# Hbase. Sequential column reading in the big row. Is it possible?

Tags: get, hbase, database-scan

I use HBase in a single-node mode. My rows in the table are huge. I have to read sequentially all columns in all rows using Java API. But Get and Scan operations return entire row (which results contains of ALL columns from the row). A lot of RAM is required. So, what should I do in case of some rows are above available RAM? Is it possible to read columns sequentially one by one?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. I have used setBatch(int batch) method in Scan class. So each next() Scanner's method call returns no more than fixed number of columns.